# Very confusing audit (maybe a bug?)

Tags: bug, review, review-audits

I just came across [this review audit](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/773320) which really confused me a lot. My first urge was to flag it and this confronted me with the following dialog (see screen-shot):

[image]

I finally simply down-voted this and passed the audit this way, but that would not have been an ideal choice in a real first post review. So is this a bug?

Comment: I had that once. It was a post I had already flagged long time before and when I noticed the same message just clicked "I'm done" (there was nothing else to do really).